# Unable to shrink memory allocated to Oracle 11g

Tags: memory, oracle-11g

Recently I have installed Oracle 11g (11.2.0.1.0) on my Windows 7 desktop having 1GB RAM, and while installation I have allocated 512 MB RAM to Oracle which causes high memory utilization and reduction is PC performance while running Oracle.

As I am using Oracle 11g for learning purpose, I want to shrink memory from 512 to 256 MB  I tried to do it from enterprise manager > Memory advisors, changing following parameter

**OLD:**

Total Memory Size = 500 MB
Maximum Memory Size = 500 MB

**New:**

Total Memory Size = 256 MB
Maximum Memory Size = 256 MB

Showing the following error:

```
"memoryMaxTarget - Maximum Memory Size cannot be less than Maximum SGA Size."
```

Can anybody tell me how to shrink the memory using enterprise Manager and using SQL*Pluse?

Comment: Most memory is super cheap, can I ask why you just don't add another real 1gb of memory?

Comment: If it says it can not be less than the SGA size you need to find and reduce that first.

Comment: that the question how to reduce SGA size!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

(Adjust your scope accordingly)

alter system set sga_max_size=256M scope=spfile;

ALTER SYSTEM SET MEMORY_MAX_TARGET = 256M SCOPE = SPFILE;

shu immediate

startup

show parameter sga

Comment: FYI: A reduction in RAM for oracle will probably hurt the database performance.